# Mayan EDMS - not showing the uploaded docs

Tags: python, django, mayanedms

I'm working on a project to use one of the open source document system and work customize it based on the need, so I'm start installing Mayan EDMS with the following steps:

1. Clone the repository https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms
2. Create a virtual environment `python3 -m venv venv`
3. Activate the environment `source venv/bin/activate`
4. Install the requirements `pip install -r requirements.txt`
5. Run `./manage.py common_initial_setup`
6. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`
7. Run `python manage.py migrate`
8. Run the server `python manage.py runserver`

All these steps done without errors but when access the Mayan on my local host and try to upload a document, this message appears but I cannot see the doc anywhere!
[The message appears after uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iPiU.png)

Known that I can see the docs in the mayan/media/shared_files but the SQLite is empty and while uploading there is no any error!
I search a lot to figure out the issue but I cannot find any solution

I appreciate your support in this issue